# Get Frequency Response of Decimated Filter with unit impluse function

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I am working with **CIC-decimator** with **sigma-delta** implementation. Now I want to check it's **frequency response**, Let us say: I implementted them with python, I have **no filter coefficients**. So I simulate this in matlab with method "fft+abs+20*log10(x)" like below:

```
clear all; close all; clc

R = 1; % Decimation Factor
D = 4; % Comb Delay
S = 3; % Sections

cicDecim = dsp.CICDecimator(R,D,S);
cicdec.FixedPointDataType = 'Minimum section word lengths'; 
cicdec.OutputWordLength = 16;

N = 512
x = [1;zeros(N-1,1)]; % unit impluse respose
y = double(cicDecim(x));
fy = 20 * log10(abs(fft(y)));
plot(fy)


h=fvtool(cicDecim,'Fs',16000);
h.NormalizeMagnitudeto1 = 'on';
```

when **R = 1**, everything is ok, I can see the two is almost the same(ignore the magnitude ,but just forcus the shape):
[image]

But when **R > 1,** like 2, they are different(It seems that I lost some side slobes):
[image]
I am not good at dsp, and I don't know what's wrong with my code, it takes me two days, I need help T_T~~~~~
PS:I just want to check my own frequency response based on unit impluse response is right, If it is right, the two should the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Because of R, the original D should multiply R to reserve Comb property.